# How to create a one-sided relationship with ManyToManyField('self')

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a simple 'follow' functionality in Django, like so (by the way, I'm not using `django.contrib.auth`, if that makes a difference):

```
class User(models.Model):
     followers = models.ManyToManyField('self')
     # rest of code
```

I've tested this out on my site with two users, User X and User Y...but when User X is added to User Y's followers, User Y is also added to User X's followers, which was not the intended outcome. How can I make this a one-sided relationship? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a self referential `ManyToManyField` is symmetrical. See the [following in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical):

> ...`ManyToManyField` is assumed to be symmetrical -- that is, if I am your
> friend, then you are my friend.
>
> If you do not want symmetry in many-to-many relationships with self,
> set symmetrical to False. This will force Django to add the descriptor
> for the reverse relationship, allowing ManyToManyField relationships
> to be non-symmetrical.

You can achieve it by adding:

`models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the relation [asymmetrical](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical).